# Fitting a pdf to an histogram in matlab

Tags: matlab, histogram, probability-density

I'm having troubles when fitting a pdf to an histogram in Matlab. I'm using gmdistribution.fit because my data is multi-modal.  This is what I have done:

```
data=[0.35*randn(1,100000), 0.5*randn(1,100000)+5, 1*randn(1,100000)+3]'; %multimodal data
x=min(data):(max(data)-min(data))/10000:max(data);

%Normalized Histogram
[counts,edges]=histcounts(data,500, 'Normalization', 'pdf');
bw=edges(2)-edges(1);
centers=edges(1:end-1)+bw;
H = bar(centers,counts,'hist');
hold on

%Fitting with gmdistribution
rng default
obj=gmdistribution.fit(data,3,'Replicates',5);

%the PDF
PDF=zeros(1,length(x));
for i=1:obj.NumComponents
    k=obj.ComponentProportion(i);
    u=obj.mu(i);
    sigma=obj.Sigma(i);
    PDF=PDF+k*normpdf(x,u,sigma);    
end
PDF=PDF/trapz(x,PDF);  %normalization (just in case)
plot(x,PDF)

%Fitting with ksdensity (for comparison)
[PDF2,xi]=ksdensity(data,x);
plot(x,PDF2)

legend('Normalized Histogram','gmdistribution','ksdensity')
```

[Histogram and PDFs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdH5P.jpg)

As you can see, the Gaussian Mixture doesn't fit the histogram properly. The PDF from the ksdensiti function is much better. I have also tried to fit just one gaussian. If you run the same previous code, using
   data=[0.35*randn(1,100000)]';
and
   obj=gmdistribution.fit(data,1,'Replicates',5);
you get the following

[Histogram and PDFs for one gaussian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3KHf.jpg)

Again, the pdf from gmdistribution doesn't fit the histogram. It seems that the problem is with the scaling factor in the data generation (the 0.35). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sigma` parameter of the `gmdistribution` object corresponds to the covariance, however, the `normpdf` function needs the standard deviation. The problem is fixed by replacing `normpdf(x,u,sigma)` with `normpdf(x,u,sqrt(sigma))` in the for loop.